# The edit tag feature fails to handle multiple requests at UI

Tags: bug, edits

Reproducing steps to this problem doesn't seem to be easy as per my understanding, but the screens shall help to confirm the behavior. This is what happened when I had faced the issue -

I had tried editing a question, and a possible unresponsive network didn't make it to the server (or as what I could think of). So the user in me clicked multiple times to raise multiple requests for certainty for one of them to reach. But when they did reach the server and the response came back to the UI, I saw a broken experience as the following:

[image]

This wasn't just contained to itself. When I actually tried editing the second **Tags** section in the image displayed, I would get something like this(the tags above the text):

[image]